# Interacting with a webpage using Python

Tags: python, https

I want to do a specific sets of operations using Python:

1- Access a webpage
2- Click on a page button
3- Clear cache and cookies and any other site data from the browser memory.
4- Do the above in a loop.

I'm a complete novice when it comes to interacting with the web using Python.
The language itself however I'm intermediate in.

I want some learning material that I can use to understand the basic HTTP framework and be able to interact with a webpage using Python.

Which libraries, tutorials, documentation I can use to learn further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) sounds like your best bet! It's an open-source web-based automation tool.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('http://www.yahoo.com')
assert 'Yahoo' in browser.title

elem = browser.find_element_by_name('p')  # Find the search box
elem.send_keys('seleniumhq' + Keys.RETURN)

browser.quit()
```

This snippet will remove cache, etc:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


def get_clear_browsing_button(driver):
    """Find the "CLEAR BROWSING BUTTON" on the Chrome settings page."""
    return driver.find_element_by_css_selector('* /deep/ #clearBrowsingDataConfirm')


def clear_cache(driver, timeout=60):
    """Clear the cookies and cache for the ChromeDriver instance."""
    # navigate to the settings page
    driver.get('chrome://settings/clearBrowserData')

    # wait for the button to appear
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)
    wait.until(get_clear_browsing_button)

    # click the button to clear the cache
    get_clear_browsing_button(driver).click()

    # wait for the button to be gone before returning
    wait.until_not(get_clear_browsing_button)
```

Comment: This seems optimal for my purposes.

Comment: But I still can't figure out how to clear cache, cookies...,etc. From the browser memory.

Comment: @user284081 made some changes. :)

Comment: Is there a way for me to achieve the same results of using selenium but without opening the graphical interface of chrome/Firefox?